# Perl Mail::IMAPClient date of email epoch time

Tags: perl

I use perl Mail::IMAPClient in the manner below in order to get info about emails before they are downloaded.

```
print "\tSubject: ".$imap->parse_headers($id,"Subject")->{"Subject"}->[0] . "\n";
print "\tFrom:    ".$imap->parse_headers($id,"From")->{"From"}->[0] . "\n";
print "\tDate: " . $imap->date($id) . "\n";
```

Is there an easy way to get the date of the email into epoch time?

Comment: I think you are looking for `str2time` in [Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse).

Comment: What are you calling "non-leap seconds"? Unix epoch? Unix epoch not adjusted for leap seconds?  Can you give a concrete example of what you mean?

Comment: I am calling "non-leap seconds" what perl 'time' function returns. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich  `str2time($imap->date($id))` worked and was easy, great answer. Thank you.

Comment: Well, "perl time" is just the number of seconds since the epoch. Leap seconds aren't important here.